# How do I create a psql alias for "\q"?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm using Postgres 9.5 on Ubuntu 14.04.  Even after using Postgres for a year, I can't get used to typing `\q` to exit my command line session.  My fingers just want to type "exit" or "quit".  How can I create an alias that does the same thing as `\q` in my Postgres command line session?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `\q`. Use <kbd>CTRL + D</kbd>. This sends [`End-of-file (EOF)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-Transmission_character). It works on all interactive terminals (at least the ones built with [readline](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html), afaik)

> readline returns the text of the line read. A blank line returns the empty string. **If EOF is encountered while reading a line, and the line is empty, NULL is returned. If an EOF is read with a non-empty line, it is treated as a newline.**

Most of the interactive terminals and [REPL utilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) you use, use some variation of readline or libedit. They all run in a loop that process lines. When you type <kbd>CTRL+D</kbd> your terminal inserts the EOF signal, the loops get a null pointer, and the program reads that by convention as a desire to quit.

You can't make `exit` nor `quit` an alias in psql, because psql doesn't have aliases like bash; but, both of your other utilities that use `exit` and `quit` should work with <kbd>CTRL+D</kbd>. It's a good muscle memory to develop.

Two minor footnotes...

- If you're on DOS or the newer graphical version, use <kbd>CTRL+Z</kbd> to send `EOF`. That's also the MS Word hotkey for Undo.
- I'm not actually describing what happens in UNIX either. I'm keeping it simple. <kbd>CTRL+D</kbd> really sends `End-of-Transmission (EOT)` which causes the terminal to send `EOF`.